# calling variable that before created in function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function like:

```
[function y = testf (x, beta, z)
y = sin (beta*z*x)./(x-z).^beta;]
```

The name of my function is `ave`, but when I call `ave` in Matlab I got this error:

```
[Input argument "beta" is undefined

Error in ==> ave at 2
y =sin (beta*z*x)./(x-z).^beta;]
```

What is my problem?

Comment: In your example, the function name is `testf`, what is exactly the `ave`?

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you post the source code and the actual error from Matlab. Your question is a little unclear. However, it seems to be a problem with your scope. If you create a variable outside a function, it must be passed into that function for the function to see it.

For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
myfunction(b):
    return a + b
```

will fail. The function does not know what `a` is, even though it has been initialized *somewhere*. The following *will* work:

```
a = 1
b = 2
myfunction(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**Edit:** Removed the random `c` variable.